# Where are content files stored in a monodroid application?

Tags: xamarin.android

I've got a monodroid application that has several files with configuration data that needs to be accessed at runtime.  I'm porting this over from Monotouch and there I have a directory "Stuff" that is off the root project directory.  All the files are marked as Content.

In monotouch, these files are copied to a subdirectory off the root, so just opening "Stuff/MyFile.txt" is working correctly.  In monodroid I'm getting file not found exceptions.

What is the base path for content files with Mono Droid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mono for Android (and regular Android), you need to place all these files in the Assets folder for them to be accessible from your application:

http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Guides/Using_Android_Assets